# ReactNative - leftButtonIcon is blurry in NavigatorIOS

Tags: ios, react-native, navigator

I'm using an image (png) for the left button in NavigatorIOS and using a high resolution png which is 60x60. The menu image is rather too big. If I use size of 30x30 the menu button is blurry.

I also tried to use 60x60 and then used @2x or @3x but that didn't help.

Does anyone know how to use a high res images for button images in NavigatorIOS?

Code:

```
<NavigatorIOS
                    ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
                    style={{flex: 1}}
                    navigationBarHidden={false}
                    tintColor={'#000'}
                    barTintColor = {'#D3D2DA'}
                    initialRoute={{
                        title: 'Hello World',
                        component: Home,
                        leftButtonIcon: require('./images/menu.png'),
                        onLeftButtonPress: () => { this._drawer.open() }
                    }}/>
```

Comment: Hi, since Facebook stopped supporting NavigatorIOS and is now recommending Navigator or NavigatorExperimental, maybe you should try one of these instead... NavigatorIOS and personalisation don't fit.
Cf: https://github.com/ericvicenti/navigation-rfc/blob/master/Docs/NavigationOverview.md

Comment: Did you recompile after adding the 60x60 `./images/menu@2x.png` file?